# Can we detect context inside a Lightning Component which has implemented 'force:lightningQuickAction' interface?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, winter17, executioncontext, quickaction

While working on a Lightning Component that can be invoked inside a `Lightning Record Home Page` as well as `Quick Actions`. But I need to present different User interface in both context of the component.

So when the Lightning Component is placed in `Lightning Record Home Page` it displays a Div containing some specific fields or text, while when the component is invoked from `Quick Actions`, it shows some other fields and text.

I've implemented following interfaces:

```
force:lightningQuickAction
flexipage:availableForRecordHome
force:hasRecordId
```

Is there a way I can detect the running `context` and Render (using `aura:if`) different set of container for each interface?

Comment: Detecting the context of a QuickAction for a component in general would be very useful, I agree.
For your specific problem a base-class where common logic is shared could be the a good solution, so you extend the base-class and have 2 concrete implementations doing the visual stuff. So you can add the one component to the QuickAction and the second one to the home page.