# Is there a way to detect if a Lightning Component is running in a Community or in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I have a Lightning Components and need to know if it is running inside of a Community or in Lightning Experience.

Is there a way to detect the running context?

Right now I'm checking document.location against a hardcoded Community-path but I need a general solution.

Best Idea I have so var to make it dynamic is to check for '/s/' in the URL. But I'm not sure if this is reliable for all possible Community pages. Also it feels like an hack.

After detecting the context, I also need to get the URL Prefix from the community. Again I could cut it out of the path, but would prefer otherwise.

Googling around didn't brought much. So far I found some context-aware unanswered questions here:

- [Detect community builder context](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167523/detect-community-builder-context)
- [Can we detect context inside a Lightning Component which has implemented 'force:lightningQuickAction' interface?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145041/can-we-detect-context-inside-a-lightning-component-which-has-implemented-force)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since @glls answer is not working, as a workaround we are decomposing the URL. I don't like this approach, but it looks like that Salesforce is leaving us alone on this issue.

We have put the following code inside a js utility-libray we are using via ltng:require in almost all of our components

```
utility = {
        community : {
            context: (new RegExp('.*?\/s\/','g')).exec(window.location.href) != null,
            is : function() {
                return this.context;
            }, 
            path : function() {
                let path = (new RegExp(':\/\/(.*\.com)\/([A-Za-z0-9]*\/)?s\/','g')).exec(window.location.href); 
                return this.context != null ? path[2] == undefined ? '' : path[2] : null;
            }
        },
}
```

utility.community.is will be dynamically true in case a hybrid component is running inside Community-context and false if running inside LEX-context.

To do something really useful, we need also the path of the community (can be either blank or a string). You need it e.g. to dynamically compose image-urls, attachment-urls, links, etc. so that a compo is working on ANY community AND in LEX without config or any kind of adjustment.

Comment: fyi: the answer was updated a few weeks ago with a valid approach

Comment: thanks glls, I will stick to the URL solution, because I still need to detect the community name to compose dynamic paths to files and images. As said above the APEX-way might not be dynamically enough to cover hybrid usages of session Ids. Salesforce should provide a 100% dynamic solution for context-detecion as part of the JS framework.

Answer (score 10):

You can try to use the SessionManagement Class's getCurrentSession() method, which will return a map of attributes for the users current session. Amongs these, you will find SessionType, which will indicate the context. Here are some that I tested:

Lightning Communities:

- Preview & Builder mode: SitePreview or LivePreview
- Live Site: ChatterNetworks

Lightning Experience:

- LEX App page: Aura

further details can be found at [Understanding Session Types](https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_session_types.htm&type=5)

You will have to do this in an Apex class and call your method to get the context in your clientside controller.

Comment: what happens in case of hyprid compos with `implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"`? Will the result be different in LEX vs. Community?

Comment: flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes -> will only return true in LEX,  forceCommunit‌​y:availableForAllPag‌​eTypes-> will only return true in lightning communities (ex. napili template)

Comment: cool, thats exactly what i need. will test it tomorrow.

Comment: `implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" .` I am checking following line of code `cmp.isInstanceOf("forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes")` it's returning `true` in both of the cases.

Comment: @glls it is NOT working. If an compo implements both interfaces to be usable in LEX as well as Community, it will return true regardless if the compo is exposed via LEX or via Community. So I have marked this answer wrongly as solution.

Comment: Updated, finally got a valid approach, hopefully it addresses your use case and will help other do the same.

Comment: I don't think this can detect it 100% reliably, because the sessions id is created on login. now logging into aloha as Admin, I can do a lot of things... e.g. using a deep link into LEX and now my sessionId still say aloha but in fact i can see an use LEX. Another example: log into LEX and use a deep link into community. Also you can be in different contexts at the same time using diffent browser windows and tabs... So the solution can only be an client side JS-thing, I guess... but still only a test could proof my assumptions

Comment: I have used the class to change from one environment to another, from community to an LEX app, as long as the component is embeded in the page, it will detec the changes, the domain and the environment (amongst other things) so the values are not binded to login and static.

Comment: FYI, I get "LivePreview" in the Digital Experience page builder.

Comment: thanks, added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Site.getName() will return null if NOT in a community

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_sites.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case where I needed to detect Lightning page or Community page so that I could make certain functionalities available in the Lightning page and not in Community page. I achieved this adding a property, like "isHostCommunitySite." In the Community Site, I checked this box so that when this property is true in the component, those functionlities are not available. In aura, same thing can be achieved adding a property in Design file. This is not a native way, but I think it is clean and works great.